# Hierarchical varying effects model with MVN prior

Tags: python, pymc, hierarchical-bayesian

## What I'm trying to do

I've already dealt with multivariate priors in pymc (I'm using 4.0.1), but I can't get their usage in a hierarchical model working. In my example I'm modeling a regression problem with two covariates `x1`, `x2` and an outcome `y`. There are two categorical features in the data that define hierarchy levels: `dim1` indicates the higher level category and `dim2` the lower level category.

The model consists of an intercept and a slope each for `x1` and `x2` respectively. There's a multivariate normal hyperprior `B_1` that defines varying intercepts and slopes by `dim1` in order [intercept, slope_x1, slope_x2] . These then inform the prior `B_2` on the lower level, where the terms vary also by `dim2`.

## Problem

When trying to sample from the model, I'm getting the following error: "**ValueError: Invalid dimension for value: 3**".
I interpret this as the '3' in the dims for `B_1` and `B_2` being wrong, but when evaluating the model variables manually everything seems to be fine:

`B_2.eval().shape` correctly shows that the rv is of shape (6,2,3).
The linear model in `mu` can also be evaluated without issue.

Checking the error traceback mentions this as the issue:

```
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymc/distributions/multivariate.py in quaddist_parse(value, mu, cov, mat_type)
    133     """Compute (x - mu).T @ Sigma^-1 @ (x - mu) and the logdet of Sigma."""
    134     if value.ndim > 2 or value.ndim == 0:
--> 135         raise ValueError("Invalid dimension for value: %s" % value.ndim)
    136     if value.ndim == 1:
    137         onedim = True
```

Which means that the dimensionality can't be larger than 2. This seems odd, because multivariate distributions with more than 2 dimensions are pretty common. That leads me to believe that the way I'm specifying the MVN priors is just wrong, but after much trying I'm pretty stuck.
What's the correct way of specifying `B_1` and `B_2` here?

## Code for model

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
with pm.Model(coords={'dim1':np.arange(2), 'dim2':np.arange(6)}) as mdl:
    d1 = pm.MutableData('d1', X['d1'].values, dims='obs_id')
    d2 = pm.MutableData('d2', X['d2'].values, dims='obs_id')
    # upper level
    sd_1 = pm.HalfNormal.dist(1,shape=3)
    chol_1, _, _ = pm.LKJCholeskyCov('chol_1', n=3, eta=1,
        sd_dist=sd_1, compute_corr=True)
    B_1 = pm.MvNormal('B_1', mu=[5,0,0], chol=chol_1, 
                        dims=('dim1','3')
                        )
    # lower level
    sd_2 = pm.HalfNormal.dist(1,shape=3)
    chol_2, _, _ = pm.LKJCholeskyCov('chol_2', n=3, eta=1,
        sd_dist=sd_2, compute_corr=True)
    B_2 = pm.MvNormal('B_2', mu=B_1, chol=chol_2, 
                        dims=('dim2','dim1','3')
                        )
    # regular robust regression, mu defined as linear model of covariates
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma',2)
    mu = pm.Deterministic(
        'mu', 
        B_2[d2,d1,0] + # intercept
        B_2[d2,d1,1] * X['x1'].values + # slope x1
        B_2[d2,d1,2] * X['x2'].values, # slope x2
        dims='obs_id'
    )
    outcome = pm.StudentT('outcome', nu=3, mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed=y, dims="obs_id")
    trace = pm.sample(draws=2000, tune=1000, target_accept=0.95, random_seed=0)
```

## Code for data generation

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import pymc as pm

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
N = 1000
# generate covariates and categories
X = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x1': stats.halfnorm(loc=0,scale=3).rvs(N),
        'x2': stats.norm(loc=0,scale=2).rvs(N),
        'd1': rng.choice([0,1],size=N, p=[0.6,0.4]),
        'd2': rng.choice(np.arange(6),size=N, p=[0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.2]),
    }
)
# means of the parameter distributions
intercept = np.array([
    [5,5,6,7,6,5],
    [4,4,5,6,6,4]
])
slope1 = np.array([
    [0,0.7,0.3,-0.2,-1,0],
    [0.5,1,-1,0.6,-0.2,0.3]
])
slope2 = np.array([
    [0,0.7,0.3,-0.2,-1,0],
    [0.5,1,-1,0.6,-0.2,0.3]
])*1.5
# generate some random covariance matrices
corrs = []
for _ in np.arange(6):
    _,corr,_ = pm.LKJCholeskyCov.dist(eta=1,n=3,sd_dist=pm.HalfNormal.dist(1,shape=3), compute_corr=True)
    corrs.append(corr.eval())

# generate outcome 
y = np.zeros(N)
for d1 in [0,1]:
    for d2 in np.arange(6):
        ind = (X['d1']==d1)&(X['d2']==d2)
        mv = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=[intercept[d1,d2], slope1[d1,d2],slope2[d1,d2]],cov=corrs[d2]).rvs(1)
        y[ind] = mv[0] + X.loc[ind,'x1']*mv[1] + X.loc[ind,'x2']*mv[2] + rng.normal(loc=0,scale=1,size=ind.sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay after exhausting all apparent options I discovered that [this is currently not supported by PyMC](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/5383), but the approach itself would be fine if it did. Hope I can save someone time this way.